# mascara que se mueve

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, eventos

Intento enmascarar una imagen con clip-paht: circle(50px at 50px 50px); además de hacer que la mascara se mueva con el cursor.
**NOTA:** El error es que no se ¿como poner las variables **m y n** en; **"circle(50px at m n)"**?, ósea la sintaxis JavaScript, MDN no dice mucho sobre esto.

```js
let img1 = document.querySelector(".img1");

const t = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
window.addEventListener("mousemove", moverCursor);

function moverCursor(e){
    let m = e.pageX - t.left + "px";
    let n = e.pageY - t.top + "px";
    img1.style.clipPath = "circle(50px at m n)"
}
```

```css
.box {
   width: 500px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   position: relative;
}

.img1 {
   width: 450px;
   height: 240px;
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    <div class="img1">Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) debes proporcionar la posición, ya sea en pixeles o alguna otra unidad válida; ya tienes los pixeles y solo debes usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), encerrando la cadena entre acentos graves <kbd>`</kbd> y colocar cada variable con un signo de dólar y entre llaves `${variable}` para que sean remplazadas por su valor:

```js
let img1 = document.querySelector(".img1");

const t = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
window.addEventListener("mousemove", moverCursor);

function moverCursor(e){
    let m = e.pageX - t.left + "px";
    let n = e.pageY - t.top + "px";
    img1.style.clipPath = `circle(50px at ${m} ${n})`;
}
```

```css
.box {
   width: 500px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   position: relative;
}

.img1 {
   width: 450px;
   height: 240px;
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="img1">Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: gracias!!! funciona muy bien...

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma más larga de hacer lo mismo: con variables css  y ${}

```js
let img1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
const t = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
function moverCursor(e){
    let m = e.pageX - t.left  ;
    let n = e.pageY - t.top  ;
    img1.style.setProperty(`--x`,`${m}px`);
    img1.style.setProperty(`--y`,`${n}px`);
}
box.addEventListener("mousemove", moverCursor);
```

```css
.box {
   width: 500px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   position: relative;
}

.img1 {
   width: 450px;
   height: 240px;
   background-color: purple;
   --x: 0px;
   --y: 0px;
   --r: 50px;
   clip-path: circle(var(--r) at var(--x) var(--y));
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    <div class="img1">Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo<br>Hello word, hola mundo</div>
    </div>
```